# How to use Asp.net Ajax control toolkit from CDN?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cdn

Is it possible to use it without actually downloading the binaries and adding it to project as reference?

Comment: May be there is no way we can do this!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Download the toolkit project from codeplex.

Step 2) Grab the js files you need.

Step 3) Deploy to google or the CDN host of your choice.

Step 4) ...?

Step 5) Profit

Comment: hello how can we define our CND?